# ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse causing 500 error on server

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, .htaccess, wordpress

We have the following:

- WordPress static website at `https://www.domain1.com`.
- React/Django Web application at `https://www.domain2.com` with three main URIs:

  - `/`
  - `/admin`
  - `/api`

We would like them to appear like they are the same domain at `https://www.domain1.com`. I was told this could be done by setting up a [Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) on the Apache web server that is at `https://www.domain1.com`. Due to this we'd have to migrate the current `/` of `https://www.domain2.com`, to `/portal` or `/dashboard`, which is no problem.

What should happen is if there is a link to `https://www.domain1.com/portal/*`, it will serve `https://www.domain2.com/portal/*`, but will still say `https://www.domain1.com/portal/*` in the browser. Thus, it looks like the same website to the user even though it is coming from the other domain.

Anyway, so I'm attempting to modify the `.htaccess` for `https://www.domain1.com/` by adding the following to the top:

```
ProxyPass "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/portal"
ProxyPassReverse "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/portal"

# or just 

ProxyPass "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/"
```

This causes a `500` error on the entire WordPress website.

This is the entirety of the `.htaccess`:

```
ProxyPass "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/portal"
ProxyPassReverse "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/portal"

# BEGIN WpFastestCache
# Modified Time: 09-09-21 9:26:57
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=admin@domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=ad,om
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WP_FASTEST_CACHE_CSS_VALIDATOR|Twitterbot|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^\/]+\/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /nfs/c09/h02/mnt/135490/domains/domain1.com/html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE x-font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4|ico|pdf|flv|avif|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType video/webm A10368000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A10368000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A10368000
ExpiresByType image/avif A10368000
ExpiresByType image/webp A10368000
ExpiresByType image/gif A10368000
ExpiresByType image/png A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/ico A10368000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A10368000
ExpiresByType text/css A10368000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-truetype A10368000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=A10368000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache


# Redirect permanent / https://www.domain1.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

What am I screwing up here?

Comment: It's not clear why you would need to change the URL at `domain2.com` to `/portal` as well? `/portal` is presumably just to distinguish the URL to proxy at `domain1.com`?

Comment: @MrWhite After posting this and looking at the documentation again, it looks like there isn't any reason I couldn't just do `ProxyPass "/portal" "https://www.domain2.com/"`.

Comment: ...Yes, exactly.

Comment: ...except you have a mismatch of trailing slashes in that particular directive. It should be `ProxyPass /portal/ https://www.domain2.com/` - otherwise, you'll end up with a double slash at the start of the URL-path on the proxied request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) is not allowed in a .htaccess file. You need to put it directly in the Apache config.

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory